# Local retopology

Tags: modeling, retopology

I want to re topology some of the cluttered triangular faces on the model, transforming them into regular quadrilateral meshes without changing the original shape of the model. What should I do
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello you can try an Alt J (Tris to Quads) but it may not fix your topology, please show a screenshot or even share your file?

Comment: @moonboots The effect of altj is not very good. The effect I want is like the one at the edge of the cross-section in the picture

Comment: Maybe try a remesh operation? In the Data panel > Remesh > try Quads for example and see if it fits your needs?

Comment: In addition to this^ solution you could also do a post-remesh shrinkwrap modifier to the original mesh to try to get as close to the old mesh as possible with the remeshed model.